# Convert to ascii in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, hex, type-conversion, ascii

I am using Asciistr method in oracle which is supposed to convert given structure to ascii. Arabic characters are converted correctly but english are still the same while in some online converters I can see that numbers like 1 and 2 are converted to 0031 and 0032. 
Here is my method:

```
create or replace procedure replace_ascii(test_var in varchar2,valueRet out varchar2) is

begin
   select  replace (asciistr(test_var), '\', null)
   into valueRet
   from dual;           
end replace_ascii;
```

I am currently replacing numbers with their expected value in this way:

```
select replace(replace (valueRet,'1','0031'),'2','0032') 
 .... 
into valueRet
from dual;
```

But I don't want to use 'replace' 20 times to return the correct value. What is the best way to convert those characters?

1 --> 0031

2 --> 0032

A --> 0041

......

Am I missing something here? PLease check this link http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/  and try convert english numbers and letters, and check the result of the last tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to convert any string to consequence of 4 digits tuple. I think you functions should look like

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_ascii(str_a VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS 
     l_str  VARCHAR2(32767); 
     l_res  VARCHAR2(32767); 
     i      NUMBER := 0; 
     l_char VARCHAR2(1 CHAR); 
 BEGIN 
     l_str := asciistr(str_a); 
     WHILE i < length(l_str) 
     LOOP 
         i      := i + 1; 
         l_char := substr(l_str, i, 1); 
         /*l_res  := l_res || '\';*/ 
         IF l_char = '\' THEN 
             l_res := l_res || substr(l_str, i + 1, 4); 
             i     := i + 4; 
         ELSE 
             l_res := l_res || ltrim(to_char(ascii(l_char), '00XX')); 
         END IF; 
     END LOOP; 
     RETURN l_res; 
 END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   select case when length(asciistr(test_var)) = 1 then  to_char(ascii(test_var)) else to_char(asciistr(test_var)) end as value
   from dual;
```

Try this.

Comment: test_var is a structure not a character, ascii is converting 1 to 49, 2 to 50 ... this is not the solution  @Kacper

Comment: @H.Al I thought you're doing it char by char. In that case it is not solution unless you want to iterate char by char in varchar

Comment: So what is the solution? what they are doing? Any idea? @Kacper

Comment: I tried to use RawTohex but some characters are missed like: 1 is converted to 31, A is converted to 41 .... and arabic characters are converted incorrectly

Comment: @H.Al How big is data you're trying to convert?

Comment: I am getting dat afrom oracle and contructing a structure to be sent as messages with max of 150 characters

Comment: @H.Al I'm asking because you ca iterate char by char as Michael proposed but if data is very big that can get slow